# Get the list of all subscribers as well as the namespace they are listening to for monitoring purposes

Tags: nats.io

I need to create a web UI for a client company to allow them to monitor which subscribers (Microservices) are up and if they are part of a worker queue, how many of them are running.

Although this is easy to implement by keeping sending a signal to another instance of NATS (to minimize overheads) for monitoring, I would like to ask if there is any built-in feature that can provide this functionality.

This [link](https://docs.nats.io/running-a-nats-service/nats_admin/monitoring) suggests that there is a monitoring endpoint built-in but I am not sure if I can get what I need out of it. So do I have to start inventing the wheel, or is there something that can be used out of the box?